# git submodule update <name of submodule> - but still get modified: <name of submodule> (modified content)

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule and when I do `git status` I get:

```
modified:   <name of submodule> (modified content)
```

I run:

```
git submodule update <name of submodule>
```

but still get:

```
modified:   <name of submodule> (modified content)
```

Any idea why?

Comment: your wondering you didnt made any changes but it shows modified after update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `modified content` message means exactly what it says: that you have modified files in that submodule directory.  Running `git submodule update` will not discard local changes (because maybe you want those). The `update` operation is more like `git pull`; new changes will be applied as long as they don't conflict with your local changes.  If your local changes would cause conflicts, you would see something like:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    src/somefile.c
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
Unable to checkout '006d23ccca1375a973b7fae0cc351cedb41b812a' in submodule path 'name-of-submodule'
```

If you want to discard local changes, you can use the `--force` flag:

```
git submodule update --force
```

This will permanently discard any local changes you have made in that submodule directory.